# laravel unable to login because of SESSION_DOMAIN

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I set my SESSION_DOMAIN ="example.com" in my .env

now I can't login my account with correct email and password.

anybody who encounter this problem?.

Comment: do you get any errors ?

Answer (score 4):

For all experiencing this error.

When you change the SESSION_DOMAIN environment parameter, Laravel will issue new cookies but old ones are still in the browsers memory.

When the request comes from the browser to the Laravel app the old cookie has priority and therefore you are not able to login.

The solution to this is to delete old cookies in the browser (those registered without any domain, so the actual host of app).

This error typically bites those who want to add multiple subdomain persistent logins.  And what is even worse, when you have your application in production already, all your clients/users will suffer from this issue. Nobody will able to login (not only that, but mainly) to your application until they completely clear out their old cookies.

I solved this by adding a Laravel application HTTP middleware, which does it for me:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie;

class ForgotOldSessionCookies
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        Cookie::queue(new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie('laravel_session', null, now()->subYear(1)->timestamp, '/'));
        Cookie::queue(new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie('XSRF-TOKEN', null, now()->subYear(1)->timestamp, '/'));

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Be aware, when you use only this:

```
Cookie::queue(Cookie::make('laravel_session', null, -6000, '/', 'yourdomain.com'))
```

or

```
Cookie::queue(Cookie::forget('laravel_session', '/', 'yourdomain.com'))
```

Laravel will send Cookie header with the domain, so the browser will create the cookie with domain `.yourdomain.com` - that's why nothing will be deleted (different domain compared to the previous one).

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things:

1. Make sure you did not actually wrote  example.com. if this is your local, write 127.0.0.1:8000
2. Make sure to re run the server after any change in the .env file with  `php artisan serve`