# Avoid SESSION_DOMAIN applying to subdomains in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a problem with SESSION_DOMAIN in the file session.php, Laravel always adds a "." in front of my value so my cookies also apply to sub-domains. How can I avoid that?

I have the domain **example.com**, when I look in Chrome's Networks tab I see "**.example.com**" so my subdomain "dev.example.com" got two xsrf cookie: the one from the main domain and the second from the subdomain.

I would like to avoid that and have a cookie for the active domain only. Looks like in previous versions of Laravel the problem was the opposite, the "." wasn't there.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

When you want to be the cookie valid only for current subdomain keep `SESSION_DOMAIN` as `null`.

When you want to persist logins (and other session stuff) across subdomains, set `SESSION_DOMAIN` to toplevel part of your domain.

But keep in mind this issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/64261391/819364